Stuck in Children of Ug-Qualtoth
This is a horror quest mod for Fallout 4 - I'm stuck in the underground temple after assembling the skeleton on the altar and entering the chamber under the stairs that open. I got rid of the ghouls that started to animate in the side rooms, but I can't find anything else to do there. Rooms full of junk and sleeping bags, nothing further to go on.

Looking through this walkthrough video from the point where the skeleton has been assembled, the author finds a Mysterious Object in this room. This triggers the second dream. I think you can pick it up again from there. Good luck!
